# populate object_id fields in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord, auto-populate

I have two models. One named user, and one named orders. Users have an order_id field with the order's id. I have set up orders to belong to users and users to have many orders. 
Now I would like to have a view where I show some users, and each order for that user. Obviously it would be nice if I could just get one bit object that has the users and instead of the `order_id`, have the actual order. I know there are some languages where you can something like this:

```
found_user.populate(order_id)
```

Is there an option to do this in rails? I have seen the select function, but it doesn't seem to work, not with `User.find()` anyhow, which is what I am using.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you say **order belongs to user**, you should have `user_id` in **orders** table but not `order_id` in `users` table.

> Now I would like to have a view where I show some users, and each
>   order for that user.

And now in the view where you want to display the users and their orders, try the below code

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %> #assuming you have name field in users table.
  <% user.orders.each do |order| %>
    <%= order.name %> #assuming you have name field in orders table.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Where `@users = User.all` which is defined in the respected controller action.